# Why is there an ArrayList declaration within java.util.Arrays

Tags: java, arraylist

In JDK 1.7, there is an `ArrayList` declaration which is used by `asList`.

Why did they make a new `private static class` and not use `java.util.ArrayList`:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}

/**
 * @serial include
 */
private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2764017481108945198L;
    private final E[] a;

    ArrayList(E[] array) {
        if (array==null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        a = array;
    }

    public int size() {
        return a.length;
    }

    public Object[] toArray() {
        return a.clone();
    }

    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        int size = size();
        if (a.length < size)
            return Arrays.copyOf(this.a, size,
                                 (Class<? extends T[]>) a.getClass());
        System.arraycopy(this.a, 0, a, 0, size);
        if (a.length > size)
            a[size] = null;
        return a;
    }

    public E get(int index) {
        return a[index];
    }

    public E set(int index, E element) {
        E oldValue = a[index];
        a[index] = element;
        return oldValue;
    }

    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        if (o==null) {
            for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                if (a[i]==null)
                    return i;
        } else {
            for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
                if (o.equals(a[i]))
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return indexOf(o) != -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Because the `List` returned by [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) is *backed by* the given array. It wraps that array; changes to the array are reflected in the `List` and vice versa.

Also, as a result of this, the `List` returned here has a fixed size. So, it can't be an `ArrayList` because `ArrayList` can grow or shrink.

Answer (score 4):

Because the default [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) has no `ArrayList(E[] array)` constructor.

Comment: but why make a duplicate class when it can be included within the actual ArrayList?

Comment: And `Arrays.asList()` returns a fixed size array, which is not the same behavior as `java.util.ArrayList` has. They could also have called this internal implementation `SomeInternalListImpl` instead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I was thinking that they should have named it `ArrayReferenceList` since it is a reference to the underlying array. The list is a wrapper around the source array. Changes to the list effect the array and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3):

Because they're providing a List wrapper around the provided array which is O(1), rather than building an ArrayList from the elements in the array, which is O(n).

Is this causing you a problem?  If so, it's probably because you're declaring your variables as ArrayList when you should be using List

Answer (score 2):

The `asList(T... a)` methods is declared to return a fixed-size list backed by the specified array which should also be serializable and implements `RandomAccess`

`java.util.ArrayList` does not qualify for this definition (fixed size), so another type of `java.util.List` should be used.

Answer (score -1):

if you use ArrayList, fast retrieve data from Table because it's index based,
where we want fast retriving data we can use Arraylist ....

But ArrayList is not faster in the time of deleting record because rearranging the index is  more complex

Where we want more deleting record we can use LinkedList it's not index based

ArrayList Declaration

java.util.List

ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();