# private static class ArrayList in java.util.Arrays - Why?

Tags: java, arraylist

In java.util.Arrays there is a private static class called "ArrayList" defined.
It is only referred from Arrays.asList method.

What is the benifit of doing this? 
Why is java.util.ArrayList not referred instead?

Code below:

```
   /**
    * @serial include
    */
      private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there an ArrayList declaration within java.util.Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790832/why-is-there-an-arraylist-declaration-within-java-util-arrays)

Comment: Mine is more than a year older :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the benefit of doing this? Why is `java.util.ArrayList` not referred instead?

One reason is that the actual implementation class is not a public API detail.  Doing this means that they can change the implementation class it in the future ... without any risk of breaking customer code.

Another reason for doing this is that this private class implements some operations differently to `ArrayList`.  In particular operations that would involve changing the size of the list need to be implemented to throw an exception ... in order to conform to the behavior specified in the javadocs for the `Arrays.asList(...)` method.

In reality, the list returned by `Arrays.asList(...)` is a wrapper for the original array, and not a full-function, free-standing list.  This is has advantages and disadvantages:

- On the down-side, certain operations don't work; e.g. adding and removing elements.
- On the up-side, creating a wrapper is a lot cheaper than creating a first-class list out of an array.  (The latter entails copying the array contents into the list ... and that will be expensive for a large array.)

Also, there is the issue that changes to the original array are visible via the wrapper (and vice versa) ... which can be useful if that is what you need.

---

You asked this in a comment:

> a) Why return non resizable list?

Because returning a regular resizable list entails copying the array contents at some point... which is expensive.  (And if the implementation deferred the copying until a size-changing operation was performed, the relationship between the original array and the list would be really difficult to understand.  Think about it ...)

> b) Why not use `Collections.unmodifiableList` and pass the `java.util.ArrayList` object?

That doesn't achieve anything.  You still have to copy the array contents to the `ArrayList`.  The *whole point* of this "strange" behavioral spec is to *avoid* the need to copy.

Answer (score 8):

Despite the fact that the `private static ArrayList` class shares the same name as `java.util.ArrayList`, [*they behave differently* by design.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) Given that, there's no reason that the implementations should be one and the same.

> `Arrays#asList()` returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs.

Comment: What is the difference in behaviour?

Comment: @user1395908 to start, `Arrays.asList()` returns a list which cannot be resized. It's right there in the documentation, if you read it `;-)`

Comment: I read the documentation.. but am unable to understand below- a) Why return non resizable list?  b) Why not use Collections.unmodifiableList and pass the java.util.ArrayList object?

Comment: @user1395908 It means: `asList(a).add(x)` will throw an exception (because the returned list is a *fixed size* and a new item cannot be added) and `asList(a).set(n,x)` will modify the *original* array (as per "write through to the array"). Note that `asList` is typed to return the `List` *interface* (of which the utils.ArrayList and the private ArrayList classes implement).

Comment: Yep .. "will modified the original array (as per "write through to the array"). " explains it. Thanks !

Comment: Other choices could have been made, but the current implementation "creates" a List using the array passed to asList without making a copy. Avoiding a copy is more efficient and works as expected in most use cases. It also means changes -- which do not add or remove elements, but simply change the value of exising elements -- are available whether the elements are accessed through the List interface or through the original array definition.