# Why is there an ArrayList class inside Arrays class

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

in java.util.Arrays why is there an inner ArrayList class

```
private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable
```

why not use the java.util.ArrayList class, the signature is effectively same only Cloneable is the difference. Why does *Arrays.asList* not return an instance of *java.util.ArrayList*, why make another inner class for this ?

Comment: The behavior of these classes, though both are named ArrayList, are very different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [private static class ArrayList in java.util.Arrays - Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852233/private-static-class-arraylist-in-java-util-arrays-why)

Comment: Because it's a list backed by an array, and there aren't many names that concisely convey that concept. The authors presumably thought it was better to use a name that exists elsewhere than to give a meaningless arbitrary name like FoobarList