# java.util.Arrays$ArrayList vs java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

Why does `java.util.Arrays` have an inner ArrayList class instead of utilizing `java.util.ArrayList` even though they are both in the same package?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is there an ArrayList declaration within java.util.Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790832/why-is-there-an-arraylist-declaration-within-java-util-arrays) and [private static class ArrayList in java.util.Arrays - Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852233/private-static-class-arraylist-in-java-util-arrays-why)

Comment: `Arrays`  does not have an inner class `ArrayList`. When I check the source code I find `private static class ArrayList<E>`, not an inner class. From the JLS:  "An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared `static`." "The `static` keyword may modify the declaration of a member type C within the body of a non-inner class or interface T. Its effect is to declare that C is not an inner class."